NUnit3. Whether the method was called in the same class
I can't make a test that will check if a method has been called or not.
I can do it differently, check values for example, but I want to make a method.
I have two methods in same class SomeService.cs
    public void Reset(DateTime currentTime)
    {
        var lastUpdate = GetLastUpdate();

        if (ShouldReset(currentTime, lastUpdate)) // always true
           ResetValues();
    }


    public void ResetValues()
    {
        //////
    }

In the debug of the test, I'm definitely hitting ResetValues
[Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Reset_ShouldReset_123(
        [Frozen] Mock<IPreferences> mockPreferences,
        [Frozen] Mock<ISomeService> mockSomeService)
    {
        var lastUpdate = new DateTime(2024, 11, 2, 23, 50, 0);
        var currentTime = new DateTime(2024, 11, 3, 3, 00, 0);
        
        mockPreferences
            .Setup(p => p.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), null))
            .Returns(lastUpdate);
        
        var someService= new SomeService(mockPreferences.Object, default!, default!, 
            default!, default!);
        someService.Reset(currentTime);
        
        mockSomeService.Verify(x=>x.ResetValues(), Times.Once);
    }

Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.ResetValues()

what am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to write a test that checks if a method has been called

You can't, and neither do you want to. The purpose of a unit test is to test a unit of code - specifically a whole class. The purpose of mocks is to stub out other classes so that you are not testing those. Your ResetValues() does something, either changes state in the object of that class or calls methods on other classes. This is what you check if you want to find out if it's been called by Reset()

Incidentally, you've tagged this nunit but that code looks like moq
